# Inserir novo evento acordo com o dia da semana

Tags: fullcalendar

Gostaria de saber se é possível inserir um novo evento, somente de acordo com o dia da semana, ignorando os dias do mês.

Até agora, eu consegui inserir novos eventos em run-time, mas somente passando o a data no formato, `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar(
            'renderEvent',
            {
                title: 'Novo evento',
                start: '2016-04-06T08:00:00',
                end:'2016-04-06T10:30:00'
            }
            );
    });
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível inserir o dado de acordo com o dia da semana (seg, ter, qua, qui, sex ...). ?

Comment: Esse dia da semana seria pre-definido, como o dia atual, ou de acordo com uma seleção? Talvez te ajude: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/